# XmlDsig. Specify reference to element as XPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath, digital-signature

Someone, who has experience with xml digital signature, please help.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/ I understood that in xmldsig I may use code like this

```
<Signature ..>
  <SignedInfo>
  ...
    <Reference URI="#xpointer(anyXPathExpression)">
    ...
```

So, if I have such a document

```
<Document xmlns="my-document">
  <DocumentData>
    <Name>Nobuo's document</Name>
  </DocumentData>
</Document>
```

And I want sign element `/Document/DocumentData`, I may use such a signature

```
<Document xmlns="swis-document">
  <DocumentData>
    <Name>Nobuo's document</Name>
  </DocumentData>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      ...
      <Reference URI="#xpointer(/*[local-name()='Document'][1]/*[local-name()='DocumentData'][1])"> 
      ...
```

Am I right in my considerations?

I tried to specify such a URI when using class SignedXml in .Net framework. And method `ComputeSignature` failed with `CryptoGraphicsException:Malformed reference element`.

SignedXml has no support for XPath, I suppose?

Comment: Any success with that?